# How to pass class value of HTML tag into a php variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

The title may seem quite vague, sorry about that I don't really know how to phrase my question.

I'm trying to get a PHP variable to be assigned the value of a button class when the button is pressed. Sort of like this:

```
<input id="button-id" class="button-1" type="button" onclick="<?php $variable=class of button-id; // Assign the variable here ?>"
```

Obviously the syntax is wrong as I don't know how to do it, or whether it is possible.

The reason I need this is because I am doing a MySQL query which will rely on the `$variable` like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='{$variable}'";
```

This needs to be like this due to the what the query is being used for.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: there has  to be a better way, but need more content, a hidden form field does come to mind

Comment: Could you answer with how I would do this.

Comment: put the id in a hidden form field that would be submitted hen the button is pressed.

Comment: I've never used hidden form fields before, could you explain in an answer please

Comment: A common mistake I've seen here on SO comes down to this: The php can't do something when the onclick fires because the php runs on the server *before* the page is even sent to the browser, so the php doesn't exist by the time the browser gets it. The javascript runs in the browser and can only affect the php by doing a new (Ajax or normal) GET or POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you can't do it that way.

What you probably want to do is use a hidden field to pass data to a PHP script by submitting a form. For example:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="button-1" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

Your `form.php` file would look something like this:

```
<?php

$user = 'example';
$pass = 'example';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

// use a prepared statement!
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");

// the user input is automatically quoted, so no risk of SQL injection
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['variable']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
```

Of course, rather than printing the results of the query right there, you would probably want to store them in a variable for later use. Note that you could also incorporate the script on the same page as the form.

Comment: In effect this is the way I did it. I used the form and post method

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, try this: I used Jquery to pass the button class to an Ajax request that goes to the php file below.

**EDIT:** Be sure you are correctly parsing and filtering your data to prevent injection attacks. This simply shows you you can pass html classes to PHP.

**HTML FILE**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Assign your button an on click event using jquery
        $('#button-id').click(function(){ 
            //Store our current elements class value
            var buttonclass = $(this).attr("class");
            //Create an ajax request that goes to aphp file and will receive your class value
            $.ajax({
              url: 'ajaxfile.php?buttonclass='+buttonclass,
              success:function(data){
                alert(data);
              }
            });
        }); 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="button-id" class="button-1" type="button"  />
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=newdbnaem;host=1.1.1.1:1111", "owner",  "passwordlulz");

    $buttonclass = $_GET['buttonclass'];
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = :name");
    $query->execute(array(':name' => $buttonclass));

?>
Success
<?php exit(0);
?>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Yes. Never build SQL statements by concatenating variables to partial-statement strings. Never.

Comment: Well, this question is not about Security, but you are correct, he will need to filter the data correctly but this does show him 1 solution to his question.